# ZF2 PHPUnit Assert Exception in AbstractHttpControllerTestCase Helper Method

Tags: exception, zend-framework2, phpunit

How do I test that the exception is thrown in this method when it is not a dispatched action?  (This would occur in terms of a unit test for a Controller from a AbstractHttpControllerTestCase.)

```
public function myMethodHelper($status, $message) {
    throw new DomainException($status, $message);
}
```

Attempts at using try/catch does not catch the exception but ends in the exception being thrown (an error rather than failure):

```
/**
 * @covers Application\Controller\MyController::myMethodHelper
 */
public function testMyMethodHelper() {
    // $this->object is instantiated in setUp() as the Controller to be tested.
    try {
        $this->object->myMethodHelper(500, 'The message to check.');
    } catch (\Zend\Stdlib\Exception\DomainException $exc) {
        $this->assertEquals($exc-getMessage(), 'The message to check.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using Zend Framework 2.3 and the AbstractHttpControllerTestCase, I was able to assert an exception, message, and exception code using the following annotations (assuming I return a DomainException with error code 500 as an example):

```
/**
 * @covers Application\Controller\MyController::myMethodHelper
 * @expectedException Zend\Stdlib\Exception\DomainException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage The message to check.
 * @expectedExceptionCode 500
 */
public function testMyMethodHelper() {
    // Annotations deal with expected exception, so no code is needed.
    $this->object->responder(500, 'The message to check.');
    $this->fail('Exception failed to be thrown.');
}
```